How are file sets supposed to be used in cmake?
I want to use the new file sets feature of cmake 3.28 since it seems to simplify a lot of steps (installing, exporting). However, I can't really wrap my head around what exactly is going on behind the scenes. Here's my project cmake file:
lib_file_loader/CMakeList.txt:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.28)

project(lib_file_loader VERSION 0.1.0 LANGUAGES CXX)

add_library(lib_file_loader src/file_loader.cpp)
add_library(file_loader::lib_file_loader ALIAS lib_file_loader)


target_sources(lib_file_loader
    PRIVATE
        "src/file_loader.cpp"
    PUBLIC FILE_SET HEADERS BASE_DIRS "src/include" FILES
        "src/include/lib_file_loader/file_loader.h"
)

target_include_directories(lib_file_loader
    PRIVATE FILE_SET HEADERS
    PUBLIC FILE_SET INTERFACE_HEADERS
)

message(STATUS "Interface headers: ${lib_file_loader_INTERFACE_HEADERS}")

This generates ok, however the output of the interface headers is empty:
-- Interface headers:  <--- i expected this to be filled
-- Configuring done (0.0s)
-- Generating done (0.0s)
-- Build files have been written to: /home/myuser/../file_loader/build

The way I thought this would work was for cmake to detect automatically that I want to create a file set of type HEADERS for PUBLIC headers and it would choose the INTERFACE_HEADERS set for me to populate the files into. This however doesn't seem to be the case.
So I thought ok maybe I need to specify the fileset name explicitely, so I changed the ?target_sources line to this:
PUBLIC FILE_SET INTERFACE_HEADERS TYPE HEADERS BASE_DIRS "src/include" FILES

But this gives me an error saying that:
CMake Error at lib_file_loader/CMakeLists.txt:9 (target_sources):
  target_sources Non-default file set name must contain only letters,
  numbers, and underscores, and must not start with a capital letter or
  underscore

I'm a bit lost on how to populate the interface header set to retrieve it later for target_include_directories. Things I also hoped for (but seem to be mistaken) are:

target_include_directories will automatically know for file sets of HEADERS type to go into either PRIVATE or PUBLIC category without respecifying.
BASE_DIRS (what is it for anyway? I can't find anything in the documentation) to allow header files to automatically be globbed up in the said directory so I don't even have to specify them.

I like to keep my cmake minimal and thought file sets look good enough, but I don't seem to understand them properly. Can someone shed some light on the mechanics on how to use them?

@starball Ah, got it thanks. No I'm not sure that I can use file sets in target_include_directories, however, how would I go about using them then? If I can't include them in target_include_directories they're kinda pointless no? I would have to populate a normal cmake variable with the headers then?

Setting a property doesn't also set a variable. Why would you expect that message to print anything else? Look at the get_property function...

The correct version of your example project is:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.28)
project(
    file_loader
    VERSION 0.1.0
    LANGUAGES CXX
)

add_library(file_loader)
add_library(file_loader::file_loader ALIAS file_loader)

target_sources(
    file_loader
    PRIVATE
        src/file_loader.cpp

    PUBLIC
    FILE_SET HEADERS
    BASE_DIRS src/include
    FILES
        src/include/lib_file_loader/file_loader.h
)

get_target_property(hdrs file_loader HEADER_SET)
message(STATUS "Interface headers: ${hdrs}")

Then you will see
-- Interface headers: src/include/lib_file_loader/file_loader.h

In src/file_loader.cpp, you should write
#include "lib_file_loader/file_loader.h"

Note there is no need to call target_include_directories when using file sets: the correct paths are derived from BASE_DIRS. This does not imply globs. Do not use globs in CMake as all available forms of globbing are broken to various degrees.
Also note that properties are different from variables. Setting the former does not set the latter. Consult the documentation for target_sources and get_property for more detail.

Hmm and how would you install them?


I want to use the new file sets feature of cmake 3.28

File sets predate 3.28 by quite a bit. They were introduced in 3.23. Read the docs.


BASE_DIRS (what is it for anyway? I can't find anything in the documentation) to allow header files to automatically be globbed up in the said directory so I don't even have to specify them.

The docs you're looking for on the implications of base directories is in https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/install.html#signatures :

The directory structure relative to the file set's base directories is preserved. For example, a file added to the file set as /blah/include/myproj/here.h with a base directory /blah/include would be installed to myproj/here.h below the destination.


Maybe you're not supposed to mix signatures of target_sources like you did in your above example.
Also, target_include_directories doesn't have a FILE_SET signature. You just use target_sources. Can't fathom how you even came up with that... Did an LLM give that to you?
In any case, your signature is wrong even if mixing the non-file-set and file-set signatures is okay. Your PUBLIC FILE_SET HEADERS is missing the file set name and TYPE keyword. Quoting the docs, the file set signature is this:

target_sources(<target>
  [<INTERFACE|PUBLIC|PRIVATE>
   [FILE_SET <set> [TYPE <type>] [BASE_DIRS <dirs>...] [FILES <files>...]]...
  ]...)


So something more like PUBLIC FILE_SET my_header_set TYPE HEADERS.


I'm a bit lost on how to populate the interface header set to retrieve it later for target_include_directories.

You shouldn't even need to manually target_include_directories if you use HEADER file sets with proper base directory arguments. Quoting the target_sources docs:

INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES
If the TYPE is HEADERS, and the scope of the file set is PRIVATE or PUBLIC, all of the BASE_DIRS of the file set are wrapped in $<BUILD_INTERFACE> and appended to this property.
INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES
If the TYPE is HEADERS, and the scope of the file set is INTERFACE or PUBLIC, all of the BASE_DIRS of the file set are wrapped in $<BUILD_INTERFACE> and appended to this property.


In reply to the comment

If I can't include them in target_include_directories they're kinda pointless no? I would have to populate a normal cmake variable with the headers then?

Personally- especially since I already arrange my projects with split-header Pitchfork Layout, I just target_include_directories and register the include directory for installation instead of manually listing all my headers. It's still a little wordier than I'd like, but easier than listing all headers manually in a call to target_sources.
Nit: You don't need to populate a list variable of header paths to pass the variable to a command. You can just pass the paths to the command directly.

The CXX_MODULES file set type is another story I won't get into. I haven't played with it enough to speak on it.

Thanks for the answer. Would you mind adding a complete example of how you would write OP code correctly?
